# Word2Vec python ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack

Tags: python, word2vec

I have problems with using w2v embeddings from google news. 
I downloaded `GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz` and after running

```
gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('/home/slava/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz', binary=True)
```

I got error

> IOerror: not a gzipped file

Okay, i runned `gzip GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin` in console and 
`file GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz` now says, that it is really gzip compressed data. 
But running

```
gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('/home/slava/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz', binary=True)
```

now returns

> ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack

Full traceback:

```
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-9-c4eebc3bcdb0> in <module>()
>       1 
>       2 from gensim.models import Word2Vec
> ----> 3 model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('/home/slava/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz',
> binary=True)
> 
> /home/slava/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gensim/models/keyedvectors.pyc
> in load_word2vec_format(cls, fname, fvocab, binary, encoding,
> unicode_errors, limit, datatype)
>     205         with utils.smart_open(fname) as fin:
>     206             header = utils.to_unicode(fin.readline(), encoding=encoding)
> --> 207             vocab_size, vector_size = map(int, header.split())  # throws for invalid file format
>     208             if limit:
>     209                 vocab_size = min(vocab_size, limit)
> 
> ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

How to fix this?

Comment: I'd delete the vectors you downloaded and download again -- something seems to have gone belly up in the downloading process...

Comment: yes, there was some problems with file. Downloaded again like described here https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-download-the-Google-news-word2vec-pretrained-model-from-a-Ubuntu-terminal , everything works well

Comment: You may want to self-answer as "file was corrupted and re-downloading resolved", and eventually self-accept, so question does not appear as still pending.

Answer (score 1):

File was corrupted and re-downloading resolved